# Using Generics to encapsulate responses in Kotlin like swift

Tags: generics, kotlin

In Swift, an enumeration can be created with a generic type so that an error response can be passed back with either only a successful case or a failure case. So I can declare:

```
/// An enum that boxes API results as either success or failure cases.
public enum APIResult<T>
{
    /// The request succeeded with data.
    case success(data: T)

    /// Encapsulates the type of error along with optional user-facing description string and developer-facing debug strings.
    case failure(error: Error, response: ErrorResponse?)
}
```

and then use it like the following:

```
fileprivate func myHandler(_ result: APIResult<MyResponse>) {
    switch result {

    // #1 (API Request succeeds)
    case .success(let response):
        switch response.myField {
          // handle success 
        }
    ...
    // #2 (API Request failed)
    case .failure(let error, let response):
}
```

Having reviewed the [Generics Instructions Page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html) in Kotlin, it is unclear to me as to how to box objects in a similar way using Kotlin. Could anyone point me in the right direction to duplicate an interface like this?

Comment: Maybe sealed classes? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html

Comment: @gpunto this looks promising, I will try it thanks

Comment: You could use the std lib's existing [`Result<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/index.html) implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @AjahnCharles, the solution I ended up using was the build in [`Result<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/index.html) class which worked very well.

In java I can have:

```
public class VersionCheckStatus {

    @Expose
    String supported;

    @Expose
    String reason;

    public VersionCheckStatus(String supported, String reason) {
        this.supported = supported;
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    public String getSupported() {
        return supported;
    }

    public void setSupported(String supported) {
        this.supported = supported;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }

    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    /**
     * Provides enum translation for easily checking the status of the response object
     *
     * @return enum status
     */
    public VersionCheckManager.Status getEnumStatus() {

        if (supported.equals(VersionCheckManager.Status.YES.toString())) {
            return VersionCheckManager.Status.YES;
        } else if (supported.equals(VersionCheckManager.Status.NO.toString())) {
            return VersionCheckManager.Status.NO;
        } 
        return VersionCheckManager.Status.NO;
    }
}
```

Then define a kotlin function like:

```
override fun establishCompatibility(callback: (Result<VersionCheckStatus>) -> Unit) {
...
}
```

Which can be used with fold like this:

```
manager.establishCompatibility { versionCheckStatus ->

    var textToShow = ""
    versionCheckStatus.fold({ successResult ->
        textToShow = when (successResult.enumStatus) {
            VersionCheckManager.Status.YES -> "Yes:\n ${successResult.reason}"
            VersionCheckManager.Status.NO -> No:\n ${successResult.reason}"
            null -> "Unknown"
        }
    }, { throwable ->
        textToShow = "Exception occurred:\n $throwable"
    })

    Toast.makeText(this, textToShow, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comment, you can use sealed classes for the same purpose.

If you don't want to make your own classes (and/or you want to program functional style) you can use Arrow's predefined classes, like `Either` or more specific `Try`. They have some useful additions also.

https://arrow-kt.io/docs/arrow/core/try/